# Need to add text and links to Header

Tags: html, weebly

I am working in Weebly and trying to edit my theme. In the top header (row1), I want to add the text "Request a Free Quote" in the middle and link this text to a website page. Furthermore, I would like to add text just before the phone number that reads, "Call Today:"

Here is my existing html:

```
<div id="header">
        <div class="row1">
            <div class="search">{search}</div>
            <div class="social">{social}</div>
            <div class="phone-number">{phone:text}</div>
        </div>
```

The development site can be seen here: emilyscleaningservice2.weebly.com

I can also update the CSS if necessary...but would need some guidance in this too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your existing html to:

```
<div class="row1">
    <div class="search">{search}</div>
    <div class="social">{social}</div>
    <div class="quoteText">
      <a href="https://emilyscleaningservice2.weebly.com/free-quote.html">Request a free quote</a>
    </div>
    <div class="phone-number">Call today: {phone:text}</div>
</div>
```

Then you need to add this class to the CSS:

```
.quoteText { 
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 55px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Further to this if you want to make it mobile friendly, add the following CSS beneath the above class:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .quoteText { 
    display:none;
  }
}
```

I've tested this using inspect element so it should work fine :)

Comment: Jon - THANK YOU very much! I have made the changes, and I believe we are almost there!  I would like to get the "Request a Free Quote" centered. Also...hoping to get the Call today: 315-822-5743 all on one line rather than stacked.  Thoughts?   I owe you a coffee!

Comment: @SMathias you seem to have changed the layout from my original answer, the top bar is now full width and you've moved the number? If you put it back to the above I can look at doing what you've asked. Also if my original answer worked, please can you upvote it? Cheers

Comment: THANK YOU so very much for your assistance!! It worked perfectly!